# Can't get webcam working (VirtualBox Ubuntu 11.10 on Mac OSX 10.6.8)

Tags: ubuntu, macos, virtualbox, webcam

I installed the Guest Additions, installed the isight-firmware-tools by using the AppleUSBVideoSupport file but I still can't get access to the iSight webcam.

When I launch >vlc v4l2:///dev/video0 I get the following errors:

```
Blocked: call to unsetenv("DBUS_ACTIVATION_ADDRESS")
Blocked: call to unsetenv("DBUS_ACTIVATION_BUS_TYPE")
[0x92d492c] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Blocked: call to setlocale(6, "")
Blocked: call to setlocale(6, "")

(process:2922): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.

(vlc:2922): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(vlc:2922): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(vlc:2922): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(vlc:2922): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[0x963287c] v4l2 demux error: VIDIOC_STREAMON failed
[0x963287c] v4l2 demux error: cannot set input (Device or resource busy)
[0x96430a4] v4l2 access error: VIDIOC_STREAMON failed
[0x96430a4] v4l2 access error: cannot set input (Device or resource busy)
[0x9371104] main input error: open of `v4l2:///dev/video0' failed: (null)
```

Comment: How many webcam do you have?

Comment: One only unfortunately...

Comment: Do you have any applications in OSX  that are running and using the camera (active or background)? The error seems to indicate that something else is currently using the device.

Comment: Yes, that's what I also understood but it shouldn't be the case - I have nothing except from FireFox and VirtualBox... It seems that the light for the webcam comes on and then goes off and in the end on again (and stays like that) while the log shows the error.